# _Generic works with typedef structs or only with primitive types?

Tags: c, generics, typedef, c11

Generic **o(X)** is used to construct **Object** from several types. But GCC don't expands to typedef types.

```
warning: passing argument 1 of ‘oBytes’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   68 |    Object ovi = o(vi);
      |                   ^~
      |                   |
      |                   HashTable {aka struct _HashTable *}
../cedata.h:13:43: note: in definition of macro ‘o’
   13 |                     char        : oBytes( X , 1),         \
      |
```

**_Generic** definition of **o(x):**

```
#define o( X )  _Generic ((X),                            \
                        char        : oBytes( X , 1),         \
                        char *      : oNewFrom(STRING, X),    \
             unsigned   char *      : oNewFrom(STRING, X),    \
                        int         : oNewFrom(INT, X),       \
                        float       : oNewFrom(FLOAT, X),     \
                        short       : oNewFrom(SHORT, X),     \
                        HashTable   : oNewFrom(HASHTABLE,X),  \
                        List        : oNewFrom(LIST, X),      \
                        default     : oNew()                  \
                    )
```

All **oNewFrom** and **oBytes** return **Object**.

When `vi` which type is `HashTable` aka `struct _HashTable *` is used with this Generic at line `Object ovi = o(vi);` gcc call `char        : oBytes( X , 1),` instead `HashTable   : oNewFrom(HASHTABLE,X),`.

I made any mistake or Generic don't work with structs and typedefs?

Comment: IIRC, every expression in a generic selector has to be valid and gets checked for errors/warnings.

Comment: I presume `STRING` et. al. is an enum for the type. Due to `_Generic` limitations [as others have mentioned], why not just use the same code for all types? (e.g.) `type : oAny(STRING,&X), int : oAny(INT,&X), ...` and have `oAny` be: `void *oAny(int type,void *src)` It can do a `switch` on `type` and call the correct function (e.g. `oBytes`, `ONewFrom`, etc.).

Comment: Removing oBytes HashTable is now  expanded to oNewFrom(HASHTABLE,X) and I rethink my constructor and figured out that char is unecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a definition for every type, you could specify the calling convention to be the same for all types.

For example:

```
create_xxx(void *obj);
//xxx stands for the different types
```

Then your generic macro:

```
#define o(X) _Generic((X), \
    type1: create_type1(X), \
    type2: create_type2(X), \
    ...
```

Since the argument for the create function is an opaque pointer, the compiler will never complain about what you're passing to the function. And your function knows how to deal with the data at that address.

--- Based on your comment ---

Since i don't know exactly what you're trying to accomplish, i only provided the base usage of generics and how to avoid the given warnings.

Minimal executable code of what i meant:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct ObjectRec {
    int id;
} Object;

void* create_int(void *ptr)
{
    printf("create_int\n");
    return ptr;
}

void* create_float(void *ptr)
{
    printf("create_float\n");
    return ptr;
}

void* create_obj(void *ptr)
{
    printf("create_obj\n");
    ((Object*) ptr)->id = 0;
    return ptr;
}

#define o(X) _Generic((X), \
    int*: create_int, \
    float*: create_float, \
    Object*: create_obj \
)(X)

int main()
{
    int i = 1;
    float f = 0.5f;
    Object obj;

    o(&i);
    o(&f);
    o(&obj);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Might (also) be of interest:

[Generic selection](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/generic)

Comment: The answer is partially correct, but helped me resolve this bug. The goal is that `obj * create_xxx( xxx d )` i.e. `create_xxx` returns `Obj` and get any type. The contrary of your suggestion `create_xxx(void *obj);` however I got your point here. Thanks.

Comment: _Generics is useless. Testing o(1)  ( _Generics ( int ) )  expands to all types now. I get warning from all types!

Comment: I've added some info to my answer, hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, with `_Generic`, each expression needs to make compilation sense for the type, not only the one that is used.

```
#define o( X )  _Generic ((X),                            \
                    char        : oBytes( X , 1),         \
                    ...
                    HashTable   : oNewFrom(HASHTABLE,X),  \
                    ...
                )
```

`HashTable vi; ... o(vi)` does not compile because `oBytes( X , 1)` when `X` is a `HashTable` does not compile, even though that line is not selected.

With `int, void *, double, ...`, conversion is defined between the types.  Yet with `HashTable` as a `struct`, there lacks conversion to/from basic types.

---

I'd consider posting an alterative, yet OP's post lacks details to embark on that effort.

A typical alterative passes the address of `X` to the various functions.