# How to use C11 keyword _Generic with struct?

Tags: c, generics, keyword, c11

**Related**

- [Syntax and Sample Usage of _Generic in C11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9804371/syntax-and-sample-usage-of-generic-in-c11)
- [_Generic works with typedef structs or only with primitive types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65635580/generic-works-with-typedef-structs-or-only-with-primitive-types)
- [How do you use _Generic with structs that are typedef-ed in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69347677/how-do-you-use-generic-with-structs-that-are-typedef-ed-in-c)

Good day, everyone!

I am writing an macro that differentiate type of input struct.
I am using MinGW GCC under Windows from WinLibs: https://winlibs.com/

An example from here: [Syntax and Sample Usage of _Generic in C11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9804371/syntax-and-sample-usage-of-generic-in-c11)
works great, and I was able to write same macro(Ex. A)

```
// Example A (Single Value):

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

//
typedef int32_t     i32;
typedef uint32_t    u32;
typedef int64_t     i64;
typedef uint64_t    u64;

// any single value
#define deb_single(val)                                     \
    printf("[%s]: ", #val);                                 \
    _Generic( (val),                                        \
        default : puts("UNKNOWN_TYPE"),                     \
        i32     : printf("[%d]"   ,   (i32)val),            \
        u32     : printf("[%u]"   ,   (u32)val),            \
        i64     : printf("[%lld]" ,   (i64)val),            \
        u64     : printf("[%llu]" ,   (u64)val)             \
    );                                                      \
    printf("Func [%s], line [%d]\n", __func__, __LINE__);

i32 main()
{
    i32 A = 111;
    u32 B = 222;
    i64 C = 333;
    u64 D = 444;

    deb_single(A);
    deb_single(B);
    deb_single(C);
    deb_single(D);

    return 0;
}
```

```
// Result_of Example A:

[A]: [111]Func [main], line [35]
[B]: [222]Func [main], line [36]
[C]: [333]Func [main], line [37]
[D]: [444]Func [main], line [38]

// Endof Example A.
```

Now, almost same approach (with typeof) works with structs of two same-type values (Ex. B)

```
// Example B (Struct of two same-type values):

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

//
typedef int32_t     i32;
typedef uint32_t    u32;
typedef float       r32;
typedef double      r64; // only for printf cast

typedef struct _tag_v2i { i32 x; i32 y; } v2i;
typedef struct _tag_v2u { u32 x; u32 y; } v2u;
typedef struct _tag_v2f { r32 x; r32 y; } v2f;

// 
#define deb_struct(str)                                                     \
    printf("[%s] @ line [%d]: ", #str, __LINE__);                           \
    _Generic( (typeof(str)){0},                                             \
        default : puts("UNKNOWN_TYPE"),                                     \
        struct _tag_v2i : printf("[%d][%d]\n", (i32)str.x, (i32)str.y),     \
        struct _tag_v2u : printf("[%u][%u]\n", (u32)str.x, (u32)str.y),     \
        struct _tag_v2f : printf("[%.2f][%.2f]\n", (r64)str.x, (r64)str.y)  \
    );

i32 main()
{
    v2i vA = {111,999};
    v2u vB = {222,888};
    v2f vC = {1.5f, 5.25f};

    deb_struct(vA);
    deb_struct(vB);
    deb_struct(vC);

    return 0;
}
```

```
// Result_of Example B:

[vA] @ line [30]: [111][999]
[vB] @ line [31]: [222][888]
[vC] @ line [32]: [1.50][5.25]

// Endof Example B.
```

However, I struggle to mix single values and structs (Ex. C)

```
// Example C [/*ERRORS*/]:

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

//
typedef int32_t i32;
typedef struct _tag_v2i { i32 x; i32 y; } v2i;

// 
#define deb_struct(str)                                                     \
    printf("[%s] @ line [%d]: ", #str, __LINE__);                           \
    _Generic( (typeof(str)){0},                                             \
        default : puts("UNKNOWN_TYPE"),                                     \
        i32             : printf("[%d]"      , (i32)str),                   \
        struct _tag_v2i : printf("[%d][%d]\n", (i32)str.x, (i32)str.y)      \
    );

i32 main()
{
    i32 sA = 555;
    v2i vA = {111,999};

    deb_struct(sA);
    deb_struct(vA);

    return 0;
}

// Result_of Example C:

error: request for member 'x' in something not a structure or union
   14 |         struct _tag_v2i : printf("[%d][%d]\n", (i32)str.x, (i32)str.y),     \

error: request for member 'y' in something not a structure or union
   14 |         struct _tag_v2i : printf("[%d][%d]\n", (i32)str.x, (i32)str.y),     \

error: aggregate value used where an integer was expected
   23 |     deb_struct(vA);

// Endof Example C.
```

So, my question is: **how to make macro that takes as input single values AND struct (Ex. C)?**

Thank you!

Comment: Please don't invent your own local garage standard with some ugly `typedef int32_t i32;`. Use `int32_t`, standards exist for a reason.

Comment: CGIOne, [Formatted print without the need to specify type matching specifiers using _Generic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/115143/29485) may provide insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is that all cases of `_Generic` will be expanded with the macro. To avoid that, the type-specific part needs to be moved outside the `_Generic` expression. We can achieve this if we replace your `printf` calls with calls to custom functions - then place the parameter to those functions outside of `_Generic`.

And in order to not having to pass structs etc by value, maybe make those custom functions accept a pointer instead.

Misc code review not directly related to the question:

- Use the types from `stdint.h` instead of inventing your own non-standard types.
- Use `inttypes.h` to print them and then there is no need for casts in printf.
- No need for (currently) non-standard `typeof`.
- Don't write semicolons inside macros.
- Don't name something `str` when it isn't a string.

Cleaned up code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

typedef struct
{ 
  int32_t x; 
  int32_t y;
} v2i;

static void print_int32_t (const int32_t* obj)
{
    printf("[%"PRIi32"]\n", *obj);
}

static void print_v2i (const v2i* obj)
{
    printf("[%"PRIi32"][%"PRIi32"]\n", obj->x, obj->y);
}

#define deb_struct(obj)                            \
    printf("[%s] @ line [%d]: ", #obj, __LINE__);  \
    _Generic((obj),                                \
        int32_t: print_int32_t,                    \
        v2i:     print_v2i                         \
    ) (&(obj))

int main (void)
{
    int32_t sA = 555;
    v2i vA = {111,999};
    deb_struct(sA);
    deb_struct(vA);
}
```

Now `print_int32_t` and `print_v2i` are function designators which will be called with the `(&(obj))` part as parameter. So if we pass an `int32_t` to `_Generic`, then it will pick function `print_int32_t` and call it as `print_int32_t(&sA)`.

Output:

```
[sA] @ line [32]: [555]
[vA] @ line [33]: [111][999]
```

Comment: The problem with `&(obj)` is that it requires `obj` to be L-value. Therefore it will not work for `sA + 1`.

Comment: @tstanisl perhaps use a _compound literal_ `deb_struct((int32_t){sA + 1});`?

Comment: moreover, wrap the content of `deb_struct` macro in `do { ... } while(0)`. Otherwise `if (...) deb_struct(...);` will behave in a very unexpected way.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, it is not a solution but a workaround. The current proposition is quite inconvenient without a good reason. For example `int32_t foo(); deb_struct(foo()); ` will not work what will confuse inexperienced C programmers.

Comment: @tstanisl I take it you do not see a good solution then for OP's goal.